How do I remove a username from Firefox form completion suggestions?
When I fill out a form in Firefox, it suggests usernames that I've used before.
In this example, ***@gmail.com is a sane possibility but s is a typo that somehow got remembered

How do I remove s from the set of possible suggestions, for all sites?

I assume deleting the Firefox user profile isn’t an option?

Which operating system? Removing entries uses different keyboard shortcuts on different operating systems.

See if you can find the login & password combination among the saved ones...
Click the "hamburger menu", then Passwords


No because s is not a username for anything. It gives a list of sites and associated usernames but a) s is not in them, and b) many of those usernames do not appear as suggestions. It looks like the suggestions s and ***@gmail.com are offered for sites for which NO username is saved.

One more thing to try: use the cursor key to "select" the offending item, then hit Delete - this works in other cases, maybe here too.
